# There is an empty space down the menu in ie6 only

Tags: html, css, menu, internet-explorer-6

I have a menu, in down of the menu there is an empty space, this empty space appears in IE6 only.

**Screenshot:**

`IE6`
[image]

`Other browsers (ex: IE7+, FF, etc)`
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Main</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Questions</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#nav {
    background-color:#00376d;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
div#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
div#nav ul li {
    float:right;
}
div#nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    padding:5px 15px;
    background-color:#00376d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#02509d;
}
```

**How to fix that problem ?**

Comment: Maybe because IE6 isn't a supported browser?

Comment: @Mike Koch: `IE6 isn't a supported browser` Sorry, I don't understand you. what do you mean ? I want a hack for ie6 or something like that.

Comment: Let me make a minor correction - Windows has dropped updates for IE6 as of 2008, but they still "support" it (in terms of tech support) until April 2014.  That being said, no one makes sites tailored to work on IE6, as only 4.4% of the world is using IE6 as of Dec 2013 (primarily in China). 

http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown

Comment: is it a real question or everyone is just been sarcastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested IE6 for over a year now. It's long gone, IMHO. Anyhow, this should fix the problem for IE6 (and is a better way to code it anyhow):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">

div#nav {
    background-color:#00376d;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
div#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
div#nav ul li {
    float:right;
}
div#nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    padding:5px 15px;
    background-color:#00376d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#02509d;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Main</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Questions</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the new in your code is `overflow: hidden`, `width: 100%`, but unfortunately, still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Fixed it for me, so perhaps provide a fuller code example. There must be something else going on. Did you remove the empty div?